# Setting sbatch environment variables with srun

Tags: linux, slurm

In a [blog post by Pierre Lindenbaum](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2014/09/parallelizing-gnu-make-4-in-slurm.html), `srun` is called within a `Makefile` to run jobs. I rely on this technique, but it makes no use of `sbatch` at all, so I am missing the chance to set `sbatch`-like environment variables. Where can I put the following so SLURM knows what to do?

```
#SBATCH -J testing
#SBATCH -A account
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --begin=now
#SBATCH --mem=1G
#SBATCH -C sb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `srun` command accepts nearly all of the `sbatch` parameters (with the notable exception of `--array`). In the referred blog post, these arguments are set at the line:

```
.SHELLFLAGS= -N1 -n1  bash -c
```

so you would write

```
.SHELLFLAGS= -J testing  -A account  --time=1:00:00 --cpus-per-task --begin=now --mem=1G -C sb bash -c
```

Note that if you specify `--cpu-per-task=1`, and you keep the default of one tasks, it probably means that nodes are shared in your setup ; in that case, `--mem-per-cpu=1G` makes more sense than `--mem=1G`

Comment: Fantastic! Do all the arguments have to be inline, or can I somehow write a file with `#SBATCH`-like comments as parameters?

Comment: I think they must be online. Only `sbatch` parses the `#SBATCH` comments